# How to disable data aggregation in AWS QuickSight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have simple data analytics to display in AWS QuickSight: some date fields and amounts. QS aggregates by default all date-fields and the lowest granularity is aggregate by minute. But my need is to display all data without any aggregation at all. I have searched but not found how it could be possible disable aggregation at all? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First contribution to Stack Overflow, feels good man.
I ran into the same problem and the solution is to convert the field selected for the y-axis to a dimension rather than a measure.

[Converting fields from measure to dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooo3o.png)

Aggregations will automatically be applied to 'measure' fields and therefore they need to be converted to 'dimension'